# Custom Objects in Salesforce but Not Visible in Object Manager or Scheme Builder

Tags: custom-object, data-import-wizard, object-manager

I have some custom survey objects that I have uploaded via the data import wizard. But the objects are not available in the scheme builder or object manager. *They are in the org because I can populate them in the object manager using the URL path.* How do I get these objects to show in scheme builder and object manager.

https://xyz.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/**surveyfeed**/Details/view

The custom object **SurveyFeed** is not present in object manager and schema builder.

Comment: `SurveyFeed` looks like a standard object. Or is it `SurveyFeed__c`?

Comment: @SebastianKessel you are right. it is a standard object. I must have missed that. I am new to this project. It is still strange that I can not access it via object manager or scheme builder.

Comment: @SebastianKessel do you know if it is possible to view these standard survey objects in the scheme view?

Comment: You cannot make any object appear or disappear from there. You have no control over that screen

Answer (score 1):

Standard objects with the `Feed` suffix (and custom objects with the `__Feed` one) are a special type of object. These objects represent the posts and feed-tracked changes of an object.

You're not going to see them directly on Object Manager.

For Information on feed objects, start in the links below.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_chatter.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_associated_objects_feed.htm